# list comprehension using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a column for actuals, and predicted. I would like to make a new column using list comprehension that = 1 when actuals = predicted, 0 otherwise. I know how to do this using np.where, but I was curious to know how to do it using list comprehension.

This works using `np.where`:

```
combined['correct'] = np.where(combined.actual==combined.predicted, 1, 0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need np.where nor list comprehension:

You can use this:

```
combined['correct'] = (combined.actual == combined.predict).mul(1)
```

or

```
combined['correct'] = (combined.actual == combined.predict).astype(int)
```

Comment: second is faster  I think (+1);)

Comment: OP already knows this! "I know how to do this using np.where, but I was curious to know how to do it using list comprehension." It is not about need. It is about possibility. Can OP do it or not?

Comment: @ElisByberi I not sure how to use list comprehension here.  It makes little sense, in this situation.  You can simply allow Pandas to do intrinsic data alignment and check to see if two values are equal, then cast the boolean as an integer.

Comment: @ElisByberi, `[int(x[0]==x[1]) for x in combined[['actual','predict']].values]`, but it might be pretty slow

Comment: @MaxU Ew  -1 for so a horrid suggestion. :) Just kidding.

Comment: @ScottBoston, hey, this solution deserves it (-1) :-D